# jsf wizard tabs inserting a new record to a dataTable and moving to the next tab

Tags: jsf, primefaces, wizard

I have a prime faces wizard and it has 3 tabs, inside each tab there is a text fields and a dataTable with an add button, this add button adds the information in the fields to my database and gets shown in the dataTable, when I add a new record the wizard moves to the next tab, my problem is when I add new records, it does not show in the dataTable instantly but I have to reload my server (tomcat), but if I edited an existing record and added a new record to it in the second tab it gets shown in the dataTable immediately.

Any suggestions on whats going on I tried many ways to move the wizard from on tab to another but no luck, here is what I used:

Using Java: 
1-

```
Wizard wizard = (Wizard) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("frmExamBank:tabsId");
    wizard.setStep("tab2");
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("frmExamBank");
```

2-

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.execute("PF('wiz').next()");
```

Using p:commandButton attributes:

```
oncomplete="PF('wiz').loadStep('tab3',true)
```

Can someone explain what does true means in my attribute? and any suggestions on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you need to move to next tab when adding a new record to the datatable??

Comment: @billyHope yes and keeping the record that was added selected for the next tab

Comment: You can use the BINDING, to manipulate your dataTable and tabView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to trigger a move to next tab, when adding a new record to the dataTable is done successfully, so as you mentioned in the second solution of the question, you should add this to the add button :

```
public void addRecord() {

    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.execute("PF('wiz').next()");

}
```

Know that "wiz" is the widgetVar of the wizard, this solution should work otherwise the problem is in the add button, make sure you are updating the tab.